# Looking for POIs

Tags: transit

We are traveling from Mesa, AZ to Florence, OR and would like to plot out Elks lodges and American Legion post along the route. How would that search be done?

Comment: Have you Googled to find if the Elk lodges have a list of locations? Or the American Legion?

Comment: what is a POI? Please edit and expand your acronym.

Comment: POI typically means point of interest.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'American Legion post'?

Comment: Are you familiar with https://roadtrippers.com ?

Comment: @Masta the American Legion is a fraternity of US military veterans. It operates somewhat similar to the Freemasons - there are local organizations in many communities that hold regular meetings.

Answer (score 2):

The only states a reasonable route will take you through are AZ, CA, OR, and maybe NV.  So you can go to https://www.elks.org/lodges/default.cfm and select a state, which will return a list of lodges.  If you click on the link for the state, they give you them on a map:

AZ: https://www.elks.org/states/default.cfm?vhpID=8003

CA: https://www.elks.org/states/default.cfm?vhpID=8005

OR: https://www.elks.org/states/default.cfm?vhpID=8035

NV: https://www.elks.org/states/default.cfm?vhpID=8026

And from that you can see which you will be traveling by given your route.  I imagine a similar approach can be taken for Legion Posts.